# react, react-native, как переререндерить элемент взависимости от изменения state?

Tags: react-native, reactjs

Вывожу в рендер иконку:

```
<Icon name="ios-alarm-outline" 
      size={24} 
      color={(this.state.notification) ? "#e4e6ea": "#52befc"} />
```

Но если изменяется `this.state.notification` ничего не происходит, цвет тот же самый, как сделать чтобы цвет менялся в момент изменения state?

Comment: Какое значение было у `this.state.notification`? И на какое изменилось?

Comment: @Nick, было true, потом изменил на false

Comment: Хм...А как выглядит компонент `Icon`? Должно обновляться. Возможно, в этом компоненте есть `shouldComponentUpdate`?

Comment: @Nick, компонент icon это из библиотеки react-native-vector-icons

Comment: @Nick, у меня в state еще есть ListView, и заметил что как только меняется listview то и срабатывает смена цвета.. Но почему не срабатывает сразу.. не могу понять

Comment: @Nick, оказывается проблема была в том я назначал через 
this.state.notification = true;
а надо было через
this.setState({ notification: true });

Comment: да, `this.state... = something` не вызывает `render()`